# PHP - How do I save the path of a directory?

Tags: php, file-io

Okay, lets say I include the file from a directory named /ext/include.php (see example 1)

I want some code in the "include.php"-file to figure out the path and save it.
so the path setting for example 1 is: /ext/

The code has to work, so that if I include the file through 2 directories (see example 2).
It simply saves the path to be: /ext/ext/

I've tried with something like: `__FILE__`, but is saved the whole directory.
I only want the path between the file who is including and the file getting included.

I hope you can help a newb out. :-)
please try and keep it to oop. as i'm learning it.

If you can come with both an oop and a procedural example, that would be cool!

example 1:

```
|index.php
|+ext
|  include.php
```

example 2:

```
|index.php
|+ext
|  +ext
|    include.php
```

UPDATED/SOLVED

I can't anwser my own question for the nest 8 hours, sooo..

```
This is my temporarly soloution:
```

I believe i found an anwser to my own question.
I will come back when i'm done with my code, but here is what I found out.

I knew that by using `__FILES__` I would get the full directory of the file the piece of code existed in. And by using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` I would get the directory of the currently executing script, relative to the document root.

By knowing that I could get 2 strings i could compare them. And I can add the rest of the directory to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

So I could replace the strings that look like each other. Finally, my temporarely solution looks like this:

```
// adding the rest of the directory to $_SERVER and replacing / with \ .
    $path_incg = str_replace('/','\\','C:/xampp/htdocs'.dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/');
// taking the parent directory of the full directory to the file.
    $path_incd = dirname(__FILE__);
// replacing the parts that look exactly like each other
    self::$path = str_replace($path_incg,'',$path_incd).'\\'; 
    return self::$path;
```

Example 1: lets say that `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` aka. the file including is in `/root/including.php` and by using `dirname()` we can get `/root` and by adding the rest of the directory on both sides and replacing the `/ with \` we can get:

```
$var1 = c:\xampp\htdocs\root\
```

And by using `dirname(__FILE__)` we can get the directory of the file getting included and lets say it's in `root/inc/include.php`, then we get:

```
$var2 = c:\xampp\htdocs\root\inc\include.php
```

We can now get the directories between the two files by using `str_replace()`

```
$finalpath = str_replace($path_incg,'',$path_incd).'\\';
```

The final outcome will be: `inc\`.
If you would place the include file anywhere else in the sitemap beneath the including file, it will find the path between the 2 files.

Comment: Take a look at http://ca3.php.net/pathinfo

Comment: Probably `pwd()` can help you here, however I think it's virtually impossible to always get the correct path if you have includes which include includes for example. Why do you want this very specific path? There's probably a better solution for whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: @deceze I want the 'include'-file to know where it is, no matter where you place it in a directory. And it has to know what directories is between itself and the file, doing the including.

Comment: What do you do if the include is `include '../../foo/bar/include.php'`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the include files always exist beneath the main file in the directory structure then the following should work.

```
<?php
// Include a FilePathDiff utility.  This utility can be donwloaded at
// https://gist.github.com/joelandsman/9174942
require_once("libs/filepathdiff.class.php");

// Instantiate an instance of our FilePathDiff utility and set the base path. 
// We will reference this object in our include files to register their 
// relative paths.
$fpd = new FilePathDiff();
$fpd->setBasePath(__FILE__);

// Include some files...
require_once('ext/index.php');
require_once('ext/ext/test.php');
```

Each file you include should register it's path with our utility using the following method call:

`$fpd->registerPath(__FILE__);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe i found an anwser to my own question.
I will come back when i'm done with my code, but here is what I found out.

I knew that by using `__FILES__` I would get the full directory of the file the piece of code existed in. And by using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` I would get the directory of the currently executing script, relative to the document root.

By knowing that I could get 2 strings. And I could add the rest of the directory to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

So I could replace the strings that look like each other. Finally, my temporarely solution looks like this:

```
// adding the rest of the directory to $_SERVER and replacing / with \ .
    $path_incg = str_replace('/','\\','C:/xampp/htdocs'.dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/');
// taking the parent directory of the full directory to the file.
    $path_incd = dirname(__FILE__);
// replacing the parts that look exactly like each other
    self::$path = str_replace($path_incg,'',$path_incd).'\\'; 
    return self::$path;
```

Example 1: lets say that `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` aka. the file including is in `/root/including.php` and by using `dirname()` we can get `/root` and by adding the rest of the directory on both sides and replacing the `/ with \` we can get:

```
$var1 = c:\xampp\htdocs\root\
```

And by using `dirname(__FILE__)` we can get the directory of the file getting included and lets say it's in root/inc/include.php, then we get:

$var2 = c:\xampp\htdocs\root\inc\include.php
We can now get the directories between the two files by using str_replace()

$finalpath = str_replace($path_incg,'',$path_incd).'\';
The final outcome will be: inc. If you would place the include file anywhere else in the sitemap beneath the including file, it will find the path between the 2 files.